# In R, how do I create multiple vectors of random values based on values from a data frame?

Tags: r

I have a data frame, rT, which may have any number of columns and rows.

```
            A      B      C      D
1      69.581 62.633 59.953 59.861
2      70.118 62.705 60.171 60.126
3      71.031 62.832 60.623 60.666
4      71.684 62.998 61.191 61.256
5      72.306 63.215 61.810 61.882
6      72.850 63.411 62.447 62.470
7      73.330 63.652 63.081 63.060
8      73.750 63.919 63.660 63.679
```

I want to generate a new data frame, delT, having the same number of columns as rT (also with the same column headers), having n rows, where each column is random and uniform and the minimum value of each column of delT is based on minimum and maximum values from the corresponding column of rT. Minimum and maximum of rT won't necessarily be in the first and last row of each column.

For example, using runif:

```
runif(n, min = max(x) - min(x), max = 100)
```

where x is the appropriate column of rT. For column A of delT (based on column A of rT), runif would have max(x) = 73.750 and min(x) = 69.581.

I have tried putting this in a function and using apply, but can't make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems simple. Use your `runif` call inside a `lapply` loop.

```
n <- 8
delT <- lapply(rT, function(x) runif(n, min = max(x) - min(x), max = 100))
delT <- as.data.frame(delT)
```

Data:

```
rT <-
structure(list(A = c(69.581, 70.118, 71.031, 71.684, 72.306, 
72.85, 73.33, 73.75), B = c(62.633, 62.705, 62.832, 62.998, 63.215, 
63.411, 63.652, 63.919), C = c(59.953, 60.171, 60.623, 61.191, 
61.81, 62.447, 63.081, 63.66), D = c(59.861, 60.126, 60.666, 
61.256, 61.882, 62.47, 63.06, 63.679)), .Names = c("A", "B", 
"C", "D"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", 
"4", "5", "6", "7", "8"))
```

Comment: I figured i was missing something obvious. You and ycw provided the same answer at virtually the same time.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `lapply` to apply the function you designed to each column, and then use `as.data.frame` to convert the list to a data frame. Here I used `n = 10` as an example to generate a data frame with 10 rows. `rt2` is the final output.

```
# Set the seed for reproducibility
set.seed(123)

rt2 <- as.data.frame(
  lapply(rt, function(x){
    # Set the number of rows in the first argument
    runif(10, min = max(x) - min(x), max = 100)  
}))

rt2
           A         B        C         D
1  31.727841 95.738847 89.36341 96.443597
2  79.713069 46.036428 70.41912 90.602927
3  43.361667 68.171708 65.38332 70.251415
4  88.789441 57.812934 99.44822 80.327647
5  94.294920 11.446107 66.84688  6.185393
6   8.534725 90.111322 71.93352 49.773372
7  54.777877 25.578305 56.09675 76.768155
8  89.690409  5.437865 60.91872 24.632548
9  57.013569 33.656366 31.55106 34.421286
10 47.926847 95.508873 17.87301 26.096231
```

Data

```
rt <- read.table(text = "            A      B      C      D
1      69.581 62.633 59.953 59.861
                 2      70.118 62.705 60.171 60.126
                 3      71.031 62.832 60.623 60.666
                 4      71.684 62.998 61.191 61.256
                 5      72.306 63.215 61.810 61.882
                 6      72.850 63.411 62.447 62.470
                 7      73.330 63.652 63.081 63.060
                 8      73.750 63.919 63.660 63.679",
                 header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `tidyverse` with its `purrr` package, you can apply a function based on each column of a data.frame. Then, as you get same length vector with your function, you can bind the result in a data.frame again.

`purrr::map` lets you iterate over a list, so over the column of your data.frame. For each column, apply the function `~runif(n, min = max(.x)-min(.x), max = 100)`. As each result is of length `n`, we can bind them together. `map_dfc` is for using `map` and gives a column-bind data.frame as result.

```r
rT <- data.frame(
  A = c(69.581, 70.118, 71.031, 71.684, 72.306,
        72.85, 73.33, 73.75),
  B = c(62.633, 62.705, 62.832, 62.998, 63.215,
        63.411, 63.652, 63.919),
  C = c(59.953, 60.171, 60.623, 61.191,
        61.81, 62.447, 63.081, 63.66),
  D = c(59.861, 60.126, 60.666,
        61.256, 61.882, 62.47, 63.06, 63.679)
  )
library(purrr)
n <- 5
rT %>%
  map_dfc(~runif(n, min = max(.x)-min(.x), max = 100))
#> # A tibble: 5 x 4
#>           A        B         C        D
#>       <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1  5.954893 52.99178 35.314039 88.06139
#> 2 75.256292 11.50050 17.731318 92.13357
#> 3 10.511348 15.13069 90.662412 91.01179
#> 4 44.521538 98.34528 27.756598 53.75294
#> 5 27.128326 94.98931  6.512121 59.73266
n <- 10
rT %>%
  map_dfc(~runif(n, min = max(.x)-min(.x), max = 100))
#> # A tibble: 10 x 4
#>            A         B         C        D
#>        <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
#>  1 72.906857 71.907060 17.426403 66.71158
#>  2 16.310144 77.950989 57.590292 20.20146
#>  3 69.083519 83.131703 18.149709 88.18446
#>  4 27.283926  3.569011  7.818614 61.14583
#>  5 49.978554 45.326009 70.542656 20.57136
#>  6 23.625139 87.162790 69.688542 94.57557
#>  7 84.301649 53.648099 54.296879 78.02967
#>  8  9.086232 97.715472 61.867758 93.03181
#>  9 14.799283 64.542723 75.905285 82.73306
#> 10 18.165695 50.796225 12.418779 34.12631
```